# Can't pass an ifstream pointer in a vector through a function

Tags: c++, pointers, vector, reference, ifstream

I'm trying to make a program that'll generate a two-dimensional city. I'm taking a file with the width and length of a building (predefined) from a file and passing it through a function (place_object) that'll put it in its place in the text file.

That works all fine and well, at least it did when I just passed a singular `ifstream` object through the function. Now I have a vector of pointers to `ifstream` objects, theoretically pointing to each house object I have because you cannot simply pass an `ifstream` object into a vector.

I keep getting errors in trying to pass these pointers through a function.

I have a hard time with understanding pointers, although I understand passing by reference perfectly fine.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>
#include <conio2.h>
#include <constream>

using namespace std;

//...Structures...
struct Data
{
    int width;
    int height;
};

//...Global Variables...

//...Function Prototypes...
void set_data(Data&);
void init_map(vector< vector<char> >&, Data&);
void transfer_to_file(vector< vector<char> >&, ofstream&, Data&);
void place_object(int,int,ifstream*&,vector< vector<char> >&);

int main()
{
    //...Path Address Files...
    ofstream m("What_You_Need/map.txt");
    ifstream house_files("Data/File_Paths/houses.dat");
    //...Regular Variables...
    Data d;
    vector< vector<char> > map;

    //...Structures...
    vector<ifstream*> houses;


    //...Load Vectors...
    string path;
    house_files >> path;
    while(!house_files.eof())
    {
        ifstream ifstr(path.c_str());
        houses.push_back(&ifstr);
        house_files >> path;
    }

    //...Get Size...
    do
    {
        cout << "What's the map size? (HxW): ";
        cin >> d.width;
        cin.ignore(10,'x');
        cin >> d.height;
        if(cin.fail())
        {
            cin.clear();
            cin.ignore();
        }       
    }
    while((d.width < 300 || d.height < 300) || cin.fail());

    init_map(map,d);

    //...TEST CODE HERE...
    //...Structure Files...
    getch();
    place_object(3,3,houses[0],map);
    transfer_to_file(map,m,d);

    //...File Close...
    house_files.close();
    m.close();

    //...Misc...
    return 0;
}

//...Funtions...
void set_data(Data &d)
{

}

void init_map(vector< vector<char> > &map, Data &d)
{
    for (int i = 0 ; i < d.height ; i++)
    {
        vector<char> row; // Create an empty row
        for (int j = 0 ; j < d.width ; j++)
        {
            row.push_back('.'); // Add an element (column) to the row
        }
        map.push_back(row); // Add the row to the main vector
    }
}

void transfer_to_file(vector< vector<char> > &map, ofstream &o, Data &d)
{
    for(int i = 0 ; i < d.height ; i++)
    {
        for(int j = 0 ; j < d.width ; j++)
            o << map[i][j];
        o << "\n";
    }
}

void place_object(int x, int y, ifstream *&is, vector< vector<char> > &map)
{
    int width;
    int height;
    is >> width >> height;
    is.ignore(100,'\n');

    for(int i = 0 ; i < height ; i++)
    {
        string s;
        getline(is,s);
        for(int j = 0 ; j < width ; j++)
        {
            map[i+y-1][j+x-1] = s[j];
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
}
```

Errors: (With new code that uses the "new" operator):

```
C:\Users\r_bur_000\Documents\#PROGRAMS\Map_Generator\main.cpp   In function 'void place_object(int, int, std::ifstream*&, std::vector<std::vector<char> >&)':
111 8   C:\Users\r_bur_000\Documents\#PROGRAMS\Map_Generator\main.cpp   [Error] invalid operands of types 'std::ifstream* {aka std::basic_ifstream<char>*}' and 'int' to binary 'operator>>'
112 5   C:\Users\r_bur_000\Documents\#PROGRAMS\Map_Generator\main.cpp   [Error] request for member 'ignore' in 'is', which is of pointer type 'std::ifstream* {aka std::basic_ifstream<char>*}' (maybe you meant to use '->' ?)
117 15  C:\Users\r_bur_000\Documents\#PROGRAMS\Map_Generator\main.cpp   [Error] no matching function for call to 'getline(std::ifstream*&, std::string&)'
117 15  C:\Users\r_bur_000\Documents\#PROGRAMS\Map_Generator\main.cpp   [Note] candidates are:
53  0   c:\program files (x86)\dev-cpp\mingw32\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.8.1\include\c++\string In file included from c:\program files (x86)\dev-cpp\mingw32\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.8.1\include\c++\string
40      c:\program files (x86)\dev-cpp\mingw32\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.8.1\include\c++\bits\locale_classes.h                   from c:\program files (x86)\dev-cpp\mingw32\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.8.1\include\c++\bits\locale_classes.h
41      c:\program files (x86)\dev-cpp\mingw32\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.8.1\include\c++\bits\ios_base.h                     from c:\program files (x86)\dev-cpp\mingw32\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.8.1\include\c++\bits\ios_base.h
42      c:\program files (x86)\dev-cpp\mingw32\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.8.1\include\c++\ios                     from c:\program files (x86)\dev-cpp\mingw32\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.8.1\include\c++\ios
38      c:\program files (x86)\dev-cpp\mingw32\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.8.1\include\c++\ostream                     from c:\program files (x86)\dev-cpp\mingw32\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.8.1\include\c++\ostream
39      c:\program files (x86)\dev-cpp\mingw32\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.8.1\include\c++\iostream                    from c:\program files (x86)\dev-cpp\mingw32\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.8.1\include\c++\iostream
1       C:\Users\r_bur_000\Documents\#PROGRAMS\Map_Generator\main.cpp                    from main.cpp
1068    5   c:\program files (x86)\dev-cpp\mingw32\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.8.1\include\c++\bits\basic_string.tcc  [Note] template<class _CharT, class _Traits, class _Alloc> std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>& std::getline(std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>&, std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>&, _CharT)
1068    5   c:\program files (x86)\dev-cpp\mingw32\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.8.1\include\c++\bits\basic_string.tcc  [Note] template argument deduction/substitution failed:
117 15  C:\Users\r_bur_000\Documents\#PROGRAMS\Map_Generator\main.cpp   [Note] mismatched types 'std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>' and 'std::ifstream* {aka std::basic_ifstream<char>*}'
52  0   c:\program files (x86)\dev-cpp\mingw32\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.8.1\include\c++\string In file included from c:\program files (x86)\dev-cpp\mingw32\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.8.1\include\c++\string
40      c:\program files (x86)\dev-cpp\mingw32\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.8.1\include\c++\bits\locale_classes.h                   from c:\program files (x86)\dev-cpp\mingw32\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.8.1\include\c++\bits\locale_classes.h
41      c:\program files (x86)\dev-cpp\mingw32\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.8.1\include\c++\bits\ios_base.h                     from c:\program files (x86)\dev-cpp\mingw32\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.8.1\include\c++\bits\ios_base.h
42      c:\program files (x86)\dev-cpp\mingw32\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.8.1\include\c++\ios                     from c:\program files (x86)\dev-cpp\mingw32\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.8.1\include\c++\ios
38      c:\program files (x86)\dev-cpp\mingw32\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.8.1\include\c++\ostream                     from c:\program files (x86)\dev-cpp\mingw32\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.8.1\include\c++\ostream
39      c:\program files (x86)\dev-cpp\mingw32\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.8.1\include\c++\iostream                    from c:\program files (x86)\dev-cpp\mingw32\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.8.1\include\c++\iostream
1       C:\Users\r_bur_000\Documents\#PROGRAMS\Map_Generator\main.cpp                    from main.cpp
2793    5   c:\program files (x86)\dev-cpp\mingw32\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.8.1\include\c++\bits\basic_string.h    [Note] template<class _CharT, class _Traits, class _Alloc> std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>& std::getline(std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>&, std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>&)
2793    5   c:\program files (x86)\dev-cpp\mingw32\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.8.1\include\c++\bits\basic_string.h    [Note] template argument deduction/substitution failed:
117 15  C:\Users\r_bur_000\Documents\#PROGRAMS\Map_Generator\main.cpp   [Note] mismatched types 'std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>' and 'std::ifstream* {aka std::basic_ifstream<char>*}'
28      C:\Users\r_bur_000\Documents\#PROGRAMS\Map_Generator\Makefile.win   recipe for target 'main.o' failed
```

Comment: Post the errors, either way in `place_object` you're not dereferencing `is`.

Comment: I added the errors. How does one "dereference" is though?

Comment: You dereference by either placing a `*` before a pointer, such as `*is >> width >> height;`, or by using `->` to call a function, such as `is->ignore(100,'\n');` You should probably pass your stream as a reference however, remove the pointer from the function declaration and dereference the argument instead `place_object(3,3,*houses[0],map);`

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is here:

```
while(!house_files.eof())
{
    ifstream ifstr(path.c_str());      // 1
    houses.push_back(&ifstr);          // 2
    house_files >> path;
}
```

On line `// 1`, you're declaring an `ifstream` object *on the stack* inside of this while loop block. That means after the `while` loop ends, that object is no longer valid.

On line `// 2`, you're taking the address of that object, and putting it in your vector -- with the hopes that down the road, that address will be valid. However, as I mentioned above, once you leave the scope of the while loop, it is not.

Furthermore, you're never reserving space for *more than one* `ifstream` object. You're just constantly re-initializing the same object, and putting the same (soon-to-be invalid) address in the vector.

You want to do something like this:

```
while(!house_files.eof())
{
    ifstream *ifstr = new ifstream(path.c_str());   // 1
    houses.push_back(ifstr);                        // 2
    house_files >> path;
}
```

Use the `new` operator to allocate space on your process's heap for a new `ifstream` object. The address of this object is stored in the `ifstr` pointer. Then you can put the address of that object in your vector.

Whenever you use `new`, remember you *must* eventually free the allocated memory with an accompanying `delete`.

Comment: Fantastic! That makes a lot of sense. However, I still get errors when I call the function here, "place_object(3,3,houses[0],map);". Should I change it to, "place_object(3,3,*houses[0],map);" or something?